# Display ChartJS Data only when X is bigger than

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to display data in a line chart from ChartJS, but my goal is to show only values after a specific year.

```
data: [
                        {
                            year: '1750',
                            value: 237.4646065136893,
                        },
                        {
                            year: '1755',
                            value: 275.8525403240655,
                        },
                        {
                            year: '1760',
                            value: 306.9496192507874,
                        },
                        {
                            year: '1790',
                            value: 330,
                        },
                    ]
```

And I just want to show data later than 1755. My options scales config is the one below:

```
scales: {
                                    xAxes: [
                                        {
                                            type: 'time',
                                            time: {
                                                format: 'YYYY',
                                                stepSize: 5,
                                            },
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
```

Do you know if there is a way to set some minX >= "1750"

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data and use the filtered data to feed the chart.

With [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var newData = data.filter(function (el) {
  return el.year >= 1755
});
```